# JQuery: How to determine where click leads without actually clicking or checking the href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I want to know where a click on `$('#click_me')` element leads.

I only know that there is `$('#click_me')` element on a page (and don't know if it's wrapped in anchor tag or if redirect is managed by Js).
I must avoid going to the page this element wants me to redirect to, but I want to get that page's **url**.

Code I have by now:

```
$('#click_me').click(function() {
   return false; //not preventDefault so that parent elements are not triggered
}
```

How to determine where click event leads without actually triggering it or checking the href?

Comment: Is the element always an anchor (`<a>`) tag?

Comment: @BartJedrocha, no, it isn't necessarily (though it may be). It may also be wrapped in  anchor. Or redirect may be triggered by Js (so it may be any element).

Comment: can you show us some HTML? what are the different possibilities

Comment: @Adjit, there is no certain HTML - this may be any page (I need this for scraping ads with Watir). Element may be flash for example. If I click on it, it will lead me somewhere, but can I determine where without going to that page? I need `event.where_the_click_would_redirect` kind of thing.

Comment: what you need is some kind of link extractor in a web page. So you mean to say these links could be on `div, span, a` or any other elements

Comment: @kiran.koduru, or there just could be 'window.navigate(ad_link);' with onclick event for example.

Comment: whatever you click on, if it is redirecting you should have an href, unless there is js along with it

Comment: @Adjit, that's true, I should probably reformulate my question with 'how to determine where Js redirects on element click'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can grab the URL without going to the page:

You need to prevent the default action... which is actually clicking the link and traveling to that page.

```
$('#click_me').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hck5nvwL/

Comment: no, it will not always work, because, as I said, I don't know if `$('#click_me')` is an anchor. And I don't even know if redirect is triggered by the anchor.

Comment: @lakesare It is... try the fiddle. the page doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

My solution only works if `#click_me` is an `<a>` itself, or is wrapped in an `<a>` element:

```
$('#click_me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventdefault();
    var destination;

    if($(this).is('a')) {
        destination = $(this).attr('href');
    } else if($(this).parents().is('a')) {
        destination = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```

See proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/wx69zabp/1